# the best way to process a collection of elements?

Tags: java, collections

I have a text file which contains some pairs (String,String) line by line:

> Country USA 
>   State California 
>   City New York 
>   City Atlanta 
>   County Fairfax 
>   Country Canada 
>   City New York

My code is supposed to read the file once and keep track of the count of keys (distinct pairs) and also keep track of the order of the first occurrence of each pair. What is the best way to do it?
My legal keys are just "Country", "State", "City", and "County".
Should I create a map like

```
Map<String, Pair<Integer,Integer>>
```

and then add each key into the map and update the pair which going to keep track of the count and order??? or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Your explanation is very confused. You should first think through how to accurately describe the problem. It will help you understand it.  As you've described it, the fact that there are "pairs" doesn't affect the answer at all. All you need is a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: I'm confused. Would you just store `City` in there (and increment the counter) or a the pair `City New York` and increment the counter just for this pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me a Map or a Pair are not the right fit, I would have a inner Class :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Keys {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/main/resources/META-INF/keys"));
        scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

        Map<String, EntryInfo> stats = new HashMap<>();
        int lineCount = -1;
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            final String current = scanner.next();
            lineCount++;
            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(current)){
                continue;
            }

            EntryInfo currentEntryInfo = stats.containsKey(current) ? stats.get(current) : new EntryInfo(lineCount);
            currentEntryInfo.incrementCount();
            stats.put(current, currentEntryInfo);
        }
        scanner.close();

        for (String key : stats.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " (" + stats.get(key) + ")");
        }
    }

    public static class EntryInfo{
        private int count = 0;
        private int firstLine = 0;
        public EntryInfo(final int firstLine) {
            this.firstLine = firstLine;
        }
        public void incrementCount() {
            this.count++;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Count : " + this.count + " First line : " + this.firstLine;
        }
    }
}
```

It prints :

```
Country USA (Count : 1 First line : 0)
State California (Count : 1 First line : 2)
City Atlanta (Count : 1 First line : 6)
County Fairfax (Count : 1 First line : 8)
Country Canada (Count : 1 First line : 10)
City New York (Count : 2 First line : 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<String, Map<Integer,Integer>>`